# How to fix TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: json, angular, angular-services

I'm setting up a service and i want to use a json file with mock data to start with. However i get a TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function when i use that service with the mock data, how can i resolve this error?

Service:

```
import mockCompetitions from '../../mocks/competitions-mock.json';

export class CompetitionsService {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

  getCompetitions() {
     console.log(mockCompetitions);
     return this.http.get(mockCompetitions);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
competitions: any = [];

  constructor(private competitionsService: CompetitionsService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getCompetitions();
  }

  getCompetitions(){
    this.competitionsService.getCompetitions().subscribe(data => {
      this.competitions = data;
      console.log(this.competitions);
    }, err => console.error(err), () => console.log('Finished Loading...'));
  }
```

I expect a list of names to be printed out on the page from the json file.

Comment: and what is `mockCompetitions` and isn't it undefined? at least it is according to your code.

Comment: Is `mockCompetitions` supposed to be the json file from which you are pulling data? If so can you show the value of `mockCompetitions`

Comment: @AJT_82 sorry i forgot to mention i import the json file from another folder  in my project so mockCompetitions has that  in it.

Comment: You are using the JSON file as an url to your http get.

Comment: @jordan in that case please check if the file is in the folder within the project. If its outside your project, the browser may not be able to pick the file and hence may trigger the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use httpclient to read local json file, put the json file in assets folder as `name-of-the-file.json` and make the http request by using assets folder as url. It is important that you put it in the assets folder, so that Angular can find it. So your code should look something like this:

```
export class CompetitionsService {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

  getCompetitions() {
     return this.http.get('./assets/name-of-the-file.json');
  }
}
```

So no need to import the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JSON file as an url to your `http.get()`.
If you want to test your service using mock data, I would recommend some HTTP mocking website, like [mocky](https://www.mocky.io/). Put your JSON file there and use the URL that the site generates for you in your `http.get()`. You won't have to change anything except that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For using json file as a data provider you can use import and require.

```
import data = require('your_file.json')
console.log("data : ", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It's unable to resolve .json files at all via require. Using Angular 8